# How to arrange Row's and columns for the desired output with different screen sizes:

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

I tried searching for this, it might be that I'm using the wrong terms, but I could not find any documentation on how to do this:

On a large screen size I want the following output: 
[image]

On a smaller screen I want this output: 
**EDIT: Div 3 & 4 should say 6 columns, not 4. 
[image]

```
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12" lg="8" md="12" class="mb-4">
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12">
            DIV 1
          </v-col>
        </v-row>

        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12">
            DIV 2
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-col>
      <v-col lg="4" md="6" sm="6" cols="12" class="mb-4">
        <v-row>
          <v-col sm="12">
            DIV 3
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-col sm="12">
            DIV 4
          </v-col>

        </v-row>
      </v-col>

    </v-row>
```

Right now the issue is with this current code Div 3 & 4 are each different rows instead of in the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3&4 cols should be in the same `v-row` and add `cols="6" lg="12"`...

```
       <v-col lg="4" cols="12" class="mb-4">
           <v-row>
               <v-col cols="6" lg="12" class="blue"> DIV 3 </v-col>
               <v-col cols="6" lg="12" class="blue"> DIV 4 </v-col>
           </v-row>
       </v-col>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/RczaDbIvC7)